# problemas con el servidor no me deja en ningu momento

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: **problema de la base de datos**]
tengo un problema sobre la base de datos que me dice que tengo erros en los siguiente archivos 
archivos de la base de datos que me dice que el servidor solicito un metodo de autentificacion desconocido para el el cliente
[image: codificacion de la base de dato]
me dice la line 7 de archivo db.php 
y la linea 40 y 41 de archivo index.php[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
podria ayudarme alguien soy vastante nuevo en esto.

Comment: en tu index.php tienes incluido el archivo de conexion "db.php"..?

Comment: o esta mal el usuario y password

Comment: deberias agregar tu codigo no capturas..!!

Comment: Diego Avila si está incluido  el archivo

Comment: Gbianchi el usuario  y el pasword está puesto en default

Comment: @Janpweb Edita tu pregunta con tus respuestas. Evita responder a tu misma pregunta con respuestas que no son la solución. Para tener claro lo que debes proporcionarnos para poder ayudarte echa un ojo a [mcve] y sube el código, no capturas de pantalla, necesario para poder reproducir el fallo.

Comment: Crea un usuario nuevo, asignale contraseña y permisos sobre esa base de datos, modifica la linea 5 y 6 de db.php y haz un include del archivo db.php en el archivo index.php si no lo tienes hecho.

Comment: ya lo he cambiado y me sale lo mismo  en el index.php tengo un include a db.php me sigue diciendo lo mismo de arriba que las lineas esta mal  y me ido al archivo a  confin phpmyadmin.inc,php  y lo he puesto la contraseña y tampoco

Answer (score 0):

A no se que no lo vea yo aqui y como se podria configuralo en phaMyAdmin 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Os voy ha añadir el codigo de index.php

```html
<?php include("db.php")?>
<?php include("includes/header.php")?>


<div class="container p-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){ ?>
            <div class="alert alert-<?= $_SESSION['message_type'] ?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <?= $_SESSION['message'] ?>
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                 </button>
            </div>
        <?php session_unset(); } ?>
            <div class=" card card-body">
                <form action="save_task.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Task Title" autofocus >
                    </div>  
                       <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="description"  rows="2" class="form-control"placeholder="Task description"></textarea>
                     
                    </div>      
                    <input type="submit"class="btn btn-success btn-block" name="save_task" value="Save Task">          
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                        <th>Titulo</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Created At</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM task";
                    $result_tasks = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_tasks)){ ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row ['title'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row ['description'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row ['created_at'] ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>" class="btn btn-secondary">
                                    <i class="fas fa-marker"></i>
                                </a>
                                 <a href="delete_task.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>"class="btn btn-danger">
                                     <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                   <?php } ?>             
                </tbody>
                
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>


</div>
<?php include("includes/footer.php") ?>
```